# "No package 'coinhsl' found": IPOPT compiles and passes test, but pyomo cannot find it?

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I don't know if the problem is between me and Pyomo.DAE or between me and IPOPT. I am doing this all from the command-line interface in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL). When I run:

> JAMPchip@DESKTOP-BOB968S:~/examples/dae$ python3 run_disease.py

I receive the following output:

> WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required
>   for solver
>       ipopt Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run_disease.py", line 15, in 
>       results = solver.solve(instance,tee=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line
>   541, in solve
>       self.available(exception_flag=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/solver/shellcmd.py", line
>   122, in available
>       raise ApplicationError(msg % self.name) pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: No executable found for
>   solver 'ipopt'

When I run "make test" in the IPOPT build folder, I reecieved:

> Testing AMPL Solver Executable...
>       Test passed! Testing C++ Example...
>       Test passed! Testing C Example...
>       Test passed! Testing Fortran Example...
>       Test passed!

But my one major concern is that in the "configure" output was the follwing:

> checking for COIN-OR package HSL... not given: No package 'coinhsl'
>   found

There were also a few warning when I ran "make". I am not at all sure where the issue lies. How do I make python3 find IPOPT, and how do I tell if I have IPOPT on the system for pyomo.dae to find? I am pretty confident that I have "coibhsl" in the HSL folder, so how do I make sure that it is found by IPOPT?

Comment: Well... is the binary in your `environment path`? Technically, python is not looking for it, but pyomo does as it's (completely?) binary-call based (or to be more precise: pyomo asks the OS for it). The HSL stuff is unrelated and if you did it correctly, you won't need this *proprietary* software and Mumps will be used instead. Additionally i doubt you got it, as i think it's only available through manual request from the company (different packages).

Comment: I made a manual request to HSL, and they sent me an email with both a tar and zip file. I will work on trying to move the binary to my environment path.

Answer (score 0):

As sascha states, you need to make sure that the directory containing your IPOPT executable (likely the `build` folder) is in your system `PATH`. That way, if you were to open a terminal and call `ipopt` from an arbitrary directory, it would be detected as a valid command. This is distinct from being able to call `make test` from within the IPOPT build folder.

Comment: So, I did both the following: JAMPchip@DESKTOP-BOB968S:~$ PATH=$PATH:~/CoinIpopt/build/lib
JAMPchip@DESKTOP-BOB968S:~$ export PATH, and I still got the same error. How do I add IPOPT to my path properly?

Comment: Doing so will only set the PATH variable in your current shell. Pyomo uses subprocess to call external solvers, so you likely need to do the following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path